# Issue with start an application from the windows task scheduler using Powershell script in a Windows 2016 server

Tags: powershell

I have to start an application with a different service account user credential and this job is being done via a job created on Windows task scheduler which calls a powershell script to open up the application as the service account user. The problem is when this script is executing from task scheduler the application never starts; The same script works perfectly when I run it separately.

Below code sets up the task into the task scheduler.

```
$scriptPath = "C:\temp\SetupTask.ps1"
$action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "PowerShell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file $scriptPath 2>&1 > c:\\temp\\Setuptask.txt"
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:15
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -MultipleInstances Queue
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "RunSetup" -Principal $principal -TaskPath "\test\setup" -Trigger $trigger -Action $action -Force -Settings $settings
```

Below is the code which the task scheduler executes - SetupTask.ps1.

```
$timestamp = Get-Date
Write-Host "Setup Script Start at $timestamp"
Write-Host "Running Xapp"
& "C:\temp\RunXAppbyTask.ps1"
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "test\setup" -TaskName "RunSetup" -Confirm:$false
$timestamp = Get-Date
Write-Host "Setup Script End at $timestamp"
```

Below is the code for runXAppbyTask.ps1

```
 $username = "XXX-DDD" + "\service_account_user"
 $password = "YYYYYY"  
 $credentialsObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList    @($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

  $XAPPExeName = "XAPP.Client.DesktopUI"  
  $XAPPPath = "C:\Program Files\XAPP\XAPPClient\" + $XAPPExeName + ".exe"

  try {
    $timestamp = Get-Date  
    Write-Host "Starting XAPP Application as $username at $timestamp"  
    Start-Process -FilePath $XAPPPath -Credential ($credentialsObject) #The aplication doesn't start up, this same script works fine when ran separately.
    Start-Sleep -s 60
    $timestamp = Get-Date
    Write-Host "Started XAPP Application as $username at $timestamp" 

    try {
      $Process = Get-Process $XAPPExeName  # Always fail to get the process since the process don't get started when called from the task scheduler
      Write-Host $Process.Id "-" $Process.Name
      if (!($Process.HasExited)) {
        Stop-Process -Name $Process.Name -Force
      }
    }
    catch {
      write-host "Error Closing the XAPP Application."
    }
    }
    catch {
    write-host "Error Starting the XAPP Application."  
  }
```

I did go through the following links which seems to me calling out similar issues but I couldn't find a resolution of this problem. Please note no error being thrown script just runs successfully but the application never start. Any help here will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Thread-1](https://superuser.com/questions/1329316/script-cant-start-exe-when-run-from-task-scheduler?newreg=521fee55c2274be09539bf46a472a37d)

[Thread-2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/232eb370-148d-49b8-acd0-5b73caf834de/exe-file-from-powershell-script-does-not-run-in-task-scheduler?forum=winserver8gen)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your task requires elevated permission to execute it as I can see you are trying to access `C:\Program Files\XAPP\XAPPClient\`

Can you try running the windows task with highest privileges? You can do that by checking the box in the security options

[image]

Comment: Hi Kundan, Thanks for your response. but my task is running with highest privilege.

$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

The above piece of code is ensuring of that I believe. Is there anything you can think of? I am kind of out of ideas.

Comment: I had similar issue where windows task used to start and stop immediately. with "Run with highest privileges" option checked, it worked for me